# getElementById in a ordered list

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

I have this in the html:

```
<ul class="ei-slider-arrows">
  <li id="arrowLeft" ><img src='images/close.png'/></li>
  <li id="arrowRight" ><img src='images/close.png'/></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to add a click function on my two li "arrows" but I can't select them. I tried this:

```
this.$arrows     = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-arrows');
this.$arrowLR    = this.$arrows.children('li');
this.$arrowRight = this.$arrowLR.getElementById("arrowRight");
```

I can add a function on `this.$arrowLR` but I can't manage to select `arrowRight`.
Here I tried with `getElementById`, but I also tried with `get(0)` and `get(1)`.

Anyone has an idea why it's not working?

If I do `console.log(this.$arrowRight)` it only shows `[]` in the console in both case (`get()` and `getElementById("arrowRight")`).

Comment: Please post a little more HTML and JS - it's hard from the little bit you've posted for us to help.

Comment: So i used this which is working perfectly `this.$arrowRight = this.$arrows.find('li.arrowRight img');`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get them both by id then use this snippet:

```
var arrowsBoth = $('#arrowLeft, #arrowRight');
```

Or if you want to access them separately:

```
var arrowLeft = $('#arrowLeft');
var arrowRight = $('#arrowLeft');
```

You can also get them like this (also, this can possibly return more elements than desired):

```
var arrows = $('ul.ei-slider-arrows li');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select the elements by ID and bind the event handler to it

using jQuery

```
$('#arrowLeft').click(function(){

})

$('#arrowRight').click(function(){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go:

```
$("#leftArrow").click(hazaa());
$("#rightArrow").click(hazaa());

function hazaa(){ }
```

And you can also pass a parameter if you'd like to do **slightly** different things, depending on the arrow clicked.

```
$("#leftArrow").click(hazaa("left"));
$("#rightArrow").click(hazaa("right"));

function hazaa(direction){ alert(direction); }
```

Comment: Thx for your quick answer, the reasons is that i'd like to select the li named id="arrowRight" to add a specific function (the same after for id="arrowLeft") by doing what you shown if i click on whatever arrow it ll do the same function (i need to go left and right for a slideshow)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#arrowRight")` and `$("#arrowLeft")` in jquery should get you both left and right arrows. You can then use `on()`, `delegate()`, or `click()` to assign a handler. You could also just do `document.getElementById("arrowLeft")` or `document.getElementById("arrowRight")` to do the same selection. One of your issues above is that in `this.$arrowLR.getElementById("arrowRight");` you are attempting to use a javascript function on a jquery object which contains a list of dom elements.

Comment: the problem is that I have multiple instance of this code, i have Few different slideshow. If i add this function by using `document.getElementById("arrowRight")` the function will be fired several time for all the slideshow everytime i click !

Comment: @CharlieBurger You really shouldn't have multiple id's that are the same; that is not valid markup; id's should be unique. Non-unique id's can cause various browsers to behave unexpectidly. If you have multiple elements that should be similarly named use class's. If you use $("#arrowRight").click() the function should only fire for the element that triggers the handler not on all similarly id elements.

Comment: Yes i don't know how I forgot that. I am coming from as3 and i thought about this as different object compiled and not a list of tag in the html ! 
I think I found a solution in using :
`this.$arrowRight = this.$arrows.find('li.arrowRight img');`  which i find a lot cleaner than using $("something");
It s not perfectly working but i am getting there !
Thx